# JMeter - running a login request once and looping other requests

Tags: jmeter, load

I have a test plan that consists of three requests: login, get current bingo round and save bingo ticket. The login request has a JSON Extractor that extracts an access token variable that is sent in bingo saving request header.

I want to run the login request only once and then loop other 2 requests for one hour. Ultimate thread group has the following settings: 150 threads, initial delay of 1 sec, 10 sec startup time and hold load for 3600 secs.

The first loop controller only contains the login request and should loop once. The second loop controller is set to loop forever and contains the other 2 requests and a throughput shaping timer that I set to 15 requests per second and has duration of 3600 seconds.

This is the test plan structure:

[image]

The problem is that the login request keeps looping and doesnt execute only once when I view results in Results tree and the result I want to achieve is that test plan logins only once and then loops other requests for 1 hour.

What exactly is wrong in my test plan structure?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) to the beginning of your script
2. Use the following condition in the If controller (assumes [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)):

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${__jm__jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group__idx}==1,)}
   ```
3. Put your Login Request as a child of the If Controller

This way the `Login Request` will be executed only once **per thread**