# JMeter. How to run a HTTP Login Request only 1 time while the rest loops?

Tags: jmeter

For my load test, I need to login and get the JWT.  But I only need to do this 1 time while the rest of the request are repeated.

Currently, I have a Thread Group with Transaction Controller. And inside, I have a series of Throughput Controllers to proportion the request based on percentage.

```
|- Thread Group
   |- Transaction Controller
      | - Throughput 10%
      | - Throughput 10%
      | - Throughput 40%
      | - Throughput 40%
```

I created a separate thread group to login and copy the JWT over to the header in this thread group.  But I want to do that automatically by adding the login into this flow but it should run only 1 time.  How can I do that ?

If that is not possible, is it possible to update a variable automatically in the login and then let the load test read that variable (in a separate thread in a separate run) ?  I've tried that but the value is only updated during the run.

Thanks.

Update: I saw this thread: [JMeter - running a login request once and looping other requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266889/jmeter-running-a-login-request-once-and-looping-other-requests?rq=2)

I have a few hundred users ( thread ), but I only want to login once per run.

Update: Not able to update props.

I have used a JSON Extractor to create a AuthorizationToken and tried to put it into the props using "JSR223 Assertion" immediately after the JSON Extractor.  But on the other thread, I cannot retrieve the Token

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to login **once per user** - put the "login" request under the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller). This way each virtual user will execute "login" only during 1st iteration of the Thread Group
2. If you want to **login one time only** and then re-use the JWT token across all users - it's better to do somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) and then [pass the JMeter Variable holding the JWT token to the "normal" Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)

Comment: 1. PreProcessors work with **any** Sampler in their [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules), not only HTTP Request. 2. I think you rather need a **PostProcessor** than a PreProcessor to save the data into a FIFO queue. 3. If you need to save multiple values you will need several Post-Processors or a single [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and a piece of [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) to convert what you need into JMeter Properties.

Comment: I've updated the Question.  I try to use JSON Extractor and "JSR223 Assertion" to put the var into the properties.  I don't see the property in the other thread.

Comment: Yes... I tried using properties. But I don't know why my codes not working.

Comment: Dear, I won't open your question each hour to see whether you've "updated" it or not, if you're going to ask something unrelated to the original one consider creating a new question

Comment: Sorry.  Apologies.

Comment: I've manage to extract from one thread to another... thanks very much for your help... I've got carried away.